# How to send error 500 when webpack compilation fails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, webpack

I am trying to use React with Ruby on Rails and although it is working quite well, I would like the app to send an error (probably 500) whenever the webpack compilation fails for a request.

Right now, if the webpack compilation fails, it shows me the detailed error, however rails send a 200 OK response and the browser shows the old javascript bundle. I would rather see a crash page while developing.

```
Started GET "/dashboard/index" for ::1 at 2019-04-23 15:07:24 -0300
Processing by DashboardController#index as HTML
  Rendering dashboard/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered dashboard/index.html.erb within layouts/application (3.6ms)
[Webpacker] Compiling…
[Webpacker] Compilation failed:

...

ERROR in ./app/javascript/components/App.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react1' in '/Users/gabriel/workspace/capivareo/app/javascript/components'
 @ ./app/javascript/components/App.js 19:0-42 35:13-18 35:33-38 46:2-11
 @ ./app/javascript/components sync ^\.\/.*$
 @ ./app/javascript/packs/application.js

Completed 200 OK in 7611ms (Views: 7598.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Is it possible to make the application crash whenever the javascript compilation fails?

Comment: but you have this error only when you run on development mode so it is not necessary I guess

Comment: it is not absolutely necessary, but it would be very convenient